# Viewport size reduced after phonegap upgrade

Tags: media-queries, viewport, phonegap

The viewport size is reduced to half , after I upgrade my phonegap application 
from version 2 to version 7.So the media queries , which worked in version 2 is not working with the upgraded version.How can I resolve this issue ?Should add new media query for each page or is there any other way ?

Previously when i alert window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight I obtained 720 and 1280 . The same device after upgrading , gives 360 and 720 .